# Error Working With Paper Onboarding

Tags: ios, swift

I've been following this tutorial on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G5UkS4Mrepo but I continually get the following error at return and can't find the solution:

> Cannot convert return expression of type '(String, String, String, String, UIColor, UIColor, UIColor, UIFont, UIFont)' to return type 'OnboardingItemInfo' (aka '(imageName: UiImage, title: String, description: String, iconName: UiImage, color: UIColor, titleColor: UIColor, descriptionColor: UIColor, titleFont: UIFont, descriptionFont: UIFont)')

Around the 15:13 minute mark, he shows a functioning app based on the code he provided, yet mine is throwing an error. Here's my code:

...

```
@IBOutlet weak var onboardingView: OnboardingView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    onboardingView.dataSource = self
}

func onboardingItemsCount() -> Int {
    return 3
}

func onboardingItemAtIndex(_ index: Int) -> OnboardingItemInfo {
    let backgroundColorOne = UIColor(red: 217/255, green: 72/255, blue: 89/255, alpha: 1)
    let backgroundColorTwo = UIColor(red: 106/255, green: 166/255, blue: 211/255, alpha: 1)
    let backgroundColorThree = UIColor(red: 168/255, green: 200/255, blue: 78/255, alpha: 1)

    return[
        ("rocket", "a great rocket start", "text description", "", backgroundColorOne, UIColor.white, UIColor.white, titleFont, descriptionFont)
    ][index]
}
```

...

Docs are found here: https://cdn.rawgit.com/Ramotion/paper-onboarding/master/docs/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message, the 1st and 4th values in the tuple being returned need to of type `UIImage`, not `String`. Who ever designed this API did a poor job with their naming conventions for those two values.

Also note that you have specified that there are 3 items but your `onboardingItemAtIndex` only has an array of one value.

Comment: Awesome! I was able to figure it out based on your feedback and I do have to agree with the naming conventions and the video which was throwing me off.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
    let rocket  = UIImage(named: "rocket") as UIImage!  // implicitly unwrapped

    return [
        OnboardingItemInfo(informationImage: rocket!,
                           title: "title",
                           description: "description",
                           pageIcon: rocket!,
                           color: UIColor(red: 168/255, green: 200/255, blue: 78/255, alpha: 1),
                           titleColor: UIColor.white,
                           descriptionColor: UIColor.white,
                           titleFont: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 24)!,
                           descriptionFont: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 18)!),
        ][index]
```